# How to add multiple property sheets to visual studio 2015?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, propertysheet

I try to add multiple propertysheets to one project (I've configured one for openCV, the other one for TinyXML). However if I add this two propsheets to my project, it always finds the include Directory only for one Library (the other one doesn't work - vc says that it couldn't find the file). Does someone know how to fix this?

Thank you

Comment: There's nothing fundamentally broken in VS2015 in this sense. Presumably your path in one of the property sheets is incorrect.

Comment: Well, but it doesn't seem like this is the problem. If I change the order of the props it works for the library on top.

Comment: Ah wait, did you perhaps disable inheritance on the sheets? If you "edit" the include directories list, make sure "inherit from parent or project default" is enabled.

Comment: Ahh thanks that was it :D

Comment: Make it into a formal answer.

Answer (score 3):

Property sheets in Visual Studio basically form a stack, with the higher sheets inheriting properties from lower sheets as specified for each property. For most properties this is a simple override-or-inherit choice, but for include paths it is slightly more complex because include paths can still be added by a sheet even if property inheritance is enabled (i.e. the set of paths is merged in this case).

Failure to enable inheritance (on include paths) will suppress all earlier paths, leaving only the paths in the current sheet. To enable inheritance, go to the property manager, find the appropriate property sheet, open the page with the include paths, select "edit" from the dropdown box, and finally enable the checkbox marked "inherit from parent or project default".